# Entity Framework won't add object

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4

In the following code, I have a WCF service with a method for adding a tag to a film. In the database, there are three tables: one for tags; one for films; one for joining films and tags via a relationship.

For some reason the following code, specifically the first segment of the if..then..else statement, is not adding a new tag into the table. It isn't throwing any exceptions, it just doesn't seem to be adding anything

```
    public void AddFilmTag(string tagWordIn, int filmIdIn)
    {
        if (context.Tags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.tagWord == tagWordIn) == null)
        {
            Tag t = new Tag();
            t.tagWord = tagWordIn;

            context.Tags.AddObject(t);
            context.Films.SingleOrDefault(x => x.filmId == filmIdIn).Tags.Add(t);
        }
        else
        {
            Tag t = context.Tags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.tagWord == tagWordIn);
            context.Films.SingleOrDefault(x => x.filmId == filmIdIn).Tags.Add(t);
        }
    }
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you go inside the IF and not in the ELSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the changes back to the DB

e.g.

```
context.SaveChanges()
```

Also

Whilst this like will work

```
if (context.Tags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.tagWord == tagWordIn) == null)
```

It is more semantically correct to do

```
if (!context.Tags.Any(x => x.tagWord == tagWordIn))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info on the semantics, I couldn't figure out a better way to code it

Comment: Thinking about it further it would be even better to flip the if and else clauses then you could just do `if (context.Tags.Any(x => x.tagWord == tagWordIn))`

Comment: I would do that, but tags are shared between films, so that way a user can search a silverlight app by the tags, instead of categories, as well as tag films themselves. It wouldn't work in practise but it's just a project i'm doing to learn MVVM.

Comment: Flipping the if an else  and reversing the check would not affect the logic it would run the same code in the same circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

You're not calling `context.SaveChanges()` at any point.

Without that call, nothing would be written to the database at all.

Comment: In ef (ObjectContext) the method is called `SaveChanges()` `SubmitChanges()` is the Linq2Sql method (DataContext).